# Finding the roots of $x^{2/3} + x ^{1 / 3} − 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If the radical expression given to us is $$x^{2/3}  + x ^{1 / 3} − 2$$ now the question is to find its roots.

I want to know: Can we multiply the whole equation in this way
$$x^2 + x - 8$$ I.e. each term by ^3
or I have to take its whole cube (which can be really lengthy).

Please do share if there is any other method I could use as well.

Comment: $x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}-2=(x^{1/3}+2)(x^{1/3}-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

I presume the equation is $$x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}-2=0$$

How have  you reached to $x^2+x-8=0?$

Better use the following substitution:

$$x^{1/3}=y\implies x=y^3$$

$$x^{2/3}=(x^{1/3})^2=?$$  to form a quadratic equation $y$

Comment: I multiplied each term by ^3

Comment: @user282657, You mean if $$a+b-c=0, a^3+b^3-c^3=0$$

Comment: Yes. . . .  . . .

Comment: That is not true...$1^{2/3}+1^{1/3}-2=0$ but $1^2+1-8\ne0$ @user282657

Comment: @user282657, so you think $$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2?$$

Comment: No. I don’t think that sir @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @user282657, then $$(a+b-c)^3=?$$

Comment: Ok.That will be different.